# Dealing with repetitive events in clickstream data in R

Tags: r, clickstream

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Session | UserID | Duration(min) | id | Page# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 1 | Pg1 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 2 | Pg2 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 3 | Pg2 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 4 | Pg3 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 5 | Pg2 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 6 | Pg3 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 1 | Pg2 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 2 | Pg2 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 3 | Pg3 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 4 | Pg4 |
| 125 | 347 | 59 | 1 | Pg1 |
| 125 | 347 | 59 | 2 | Pg5 |

I would like the dataset to look like this (below) because it would eventually create a more meaningful user journey.

| Session | UserID | Duration(min) | id | Page# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 1 | Pg1 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 2 | Pg2 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 3 | Pg3 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 4 | Pg2 |
| 123 | 345 | 40 | 5 | Pg3 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 1 | Pg2 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 2 | Pg3 |
| 124 | 346 | 100 | 3 | Pg4 |
| 125 | 347 | 59 | 1 | Pg1 |
| 125 | 347 | 59 | 2 | Pg5 |

Duration (min) = the number of minutes from the beginning of the path to the last page viewed.
id = path number or path length number.

I am trying to take out subsequent repetitive events based on the session and user id, leaving the duration as is.

Comment: Why is the third row of your expected result equal to 3? Should not it be 6?

Comment: @PaulS, id = path number or path length number.

Comment: so you basically want to use `unique()` or `!duplicated()` on you data (excluding "id")?

Comment: @D.J, yeah, I think one them, grouped by session and user id. Only if the next row in the page# column is the same. I do not want to delete all duplicate values in the page# column. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: i think so, you could try unique on the whole row and simply exclude the ID column. you will have to recreate your ID column with your specifications after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library('dplyr')

df %>%
  
  # group rows by Session + UserID
  group_by(Session,UserID) %>%
  
  # filter rows where Page is different from the last Page (within group), or where last Page (within group) is NA
  filter(Page != lag(Page, 1) | is.na(lag(Page, 1)) ) %>%
  
  # create new ids
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  
  # remove grouping, for future use
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   Session UserID Duration.min.    id Page 
     <int>  <int>         <int> <int> <chr>
 1     123    345            40     1 Pg1  
 2     123    345            40     2 Pg2  
 3     123    345            40     3 Pg3  
 4     123    345            40     4 Pg2  
 5     123    345            40     5 Pg3  
 6     124    346           100     1 Pg2  
 7     124    346           100     2 Pg3  
 8     124    346           100     3 Pg4  
 9     125    347            59     1 Pg1  
10     125    347            59     2 Pg5
```